# Testing Yeoman generator with bowerInstall and/or npmInstall

Tags: mocha.js, yeoman, bower, yeoman-generator

I have a Yeoman generator that uses `this.bowerInstall()`

When I test it, it tries to install all the bower dependencies that I initialized this way. Is there a way to mock this function ?

The same goes for the `this.npmInstall()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [tests](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-bootstrap/blob/master/test/test.js) for the [Bootstrap generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-bootstrap), it contains an example of mocking the `bowerInstall()` function:

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
    this.bowerInstallCalls = [];

    // Mock bower install and track the function calls.
    this.app.bowerInstall = function () {
        this.bowerInstallCalls.push(arguments);
    }.bind(this);

}.bind(this));
```

Comment: I guess this might work. I'm not using the manual bootstrapping that the example uses so I had to go with another approach.

Answer (score 3):

I eventually went with a different approach. The method from `drorb`'s answer works if you are bootstrapping the test generators manually. If you use the `RunContext` based setup (as described on the Yeoman (testing page)[http://yeoman.io/authoring/testing.html]), the `before` block of the test looks something like this.

```
before(function (done) {
  helpers.run(path.join( __dirname, '../app'))
    .inDir(path.join( __dirname, './tmp'))  // Clear the directory and set it as the CWD
    .withOptions({ foo: 'bar' })            // Mock options passed in
    .withArguments(['name-x'])              // Mock the arguments
    .withPrompt({ coffee: false })          // Mock the prompt answers
    .on('ready', function (generator) {
      // this is called right before `generator.run()`
    })
    .on('end', done);
})
```

You can add mock functions to the generator in the `'ready'` callback, like so:

```
.on('ready', function(generator) {
  generator.bowerInstall = function(args) {
    // Do something when generator runs bower install
  };
})
```

The other way is to include an option in the generator itself. Such as:

```
installAngular: function() {
  if (!this.options['skip-install']) {
    this.bowerInstall('angular', {
      'save': true
    });
  }
}

finalInstall: function() {
  this.installDependencies({
    skipInstall: this.options['skip-install']
  });
}
```

Now since you run the test with the 'skip-install' option, the dependencies are not installed. This has the added advantage of ensuring the command line `skip-install` argument works as expected. In the alternate case, even if you run the generator with the `skip-install` argument, the `bowerInstall` and `npmInstall` functions from your generator are executed even though, the `installDependencies` function is not (as it is usually configured as above)